# datagridview double click вывод данных

Tags: c#

в datagridview вывел одну таблицу из базы данных. теперь при double Click-e на определенную строку нужно вывести данные в другую таблицу с выборкой. при клике на нужную строку необходимо получить значение конкретного столбца и по этому значению нужно сделать выборку. помогите пожалуйста разобраться как это сделать. выложу то, что пытался.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)   // Датагрид клик
    {
       

        DslamInfo info = new DslamInfo();  //  объявление формы, где должен отображаться данные второго датагрида
        info.Iptextbox.Text = dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString(); // кликом на строку вывожу один столбец на текстбокс
       
        info.ShowDialog();
       displayGriddd();
   
    }
    public void displayGriddd()  //   этим методом пытаюсь передать значение одного датагрида на второй датагрид

    {
        DslamInfo info = new DslamInfo();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT sats.port, sats.dslam.id, dslam.ip FROM sats JOIN dslam ON dslam.id = sats.dslam_id WHERE sats.dslam_id = " + dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        table.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        info.dataGridView222.DataSource = command;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть задачи, то вот решение (представил сразу в классе, чтобы было проще)

```
internal class DGVHelper<T>
{
    public int? Row { get; private set; }

    public int? Column { get; private set; }

    public DataGridView _dgv;

    public DGVHelper(DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        _dgv = dataGridView;
    }

    public T GetIdBySelectedRow(string columnName)
    {
        Row = _dgv.CurrentCell?.RowIndex;
        if (Row is null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("Должна быть выделена хотя-бы одна строка.");

        Column = GetIndexByName(_dgv, columnName);
        if (Column is null)
            throw new NullReferenceException($"Не был найден столбец с именем {columnName}");

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(_dgv.Rows[(int)Row].Cells[(int)Column].Value, typeof(T));
    }

    private int? GetIndexByName(DataGridView dgv, string name = "Id")
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
            if (column.Name.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower()))
                return column.Index;

        return default;
    }
}
```

Привяжи к методу двойного клика создание экземпляра класса и вызов метода GetValueByColumnName

Comment: к сожалению не работает ,возможно я неправильно использую код,  моя задача состоит в том что - при клике на определенную строку в датагриде получить значение одного столбца по нему сделать выборку и из базы данных  вытащит все записи принадлежащие к этому значению

Comment: Подправил код. Создавать вот так (где T - тип, к которому нужно конвертировать данные из ячейки, а ColumnName - название столбца): 
            var result = new DGVHelper<T>(dataGridView1).GetIdBySelectedRow(*ColumnName*);

Comment: Конечно, можно сделать гораздо проще - как, например, вот в этой статье https://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread329947.html, но я постарался делать универсально, чтоб не нужно было создавать 1000 и 1 одинаковую строку

Answer (score 0):

```
спасибо вам большое ! я вот по другому сделал, вроде бы работает, насколько это правильное решение не знаю .  ` private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port portShow = new port();
        
        con.Open();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT dslam.id AS 'id', sats.port, sats.name, sats.surname, sats.phone FROM sats JOIN dslam ON sats.dslam_id = dslam.id WHERE dslam.id = " + dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "", con);
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dset);
        portShow.dataGridViewPort.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        con.Close();
        portShow.ShowDialog();
    }`
```

работает, скажите, правильно так делать или уродство

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Не по теме вопроса конечно, но пожалуйста... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

Comment: Проблема вашего кода в том, что он подходит для чётко конкретного случая. Если нужно будет получить значения другого столбца? Если вы измените его название? Если переместите в другое место? Вы будете копировать/редактировать код каждый раз? Да, конечно, это может работать, но гибкости у такого кода совершенно нет. Так же, не забывайте использовать using. Думаю, создание экземпляра с именем "con" можно засунуть в него

Comment: Ещё заметил следующее: https://pastenow.ru/G895Q. Зачем вам int id, если вы её потом не используете и дважды делаете одно и тоже?

Comment: И умоляю - прочитайте про форматирование строк: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.5.php. Писать строку с "+" - крайне ужасно выглядит. Может стоит эту длинную строку разбить на несколько переменных и их сложить, чтобы повысить читабельность кода. Никому не нравится листать длинную колбасню кода, которая выходит за рамки монитора

Comment: спасибо , исправлю ,  согласен с вашим советом, и вашим предложением, то что вы предложили - наверное относится к ООП ,  мой - одноразовый.  к сожалению я еще далек от ООП... будем стремится.  даже нормально не смог разобраться вашим кодом. вот такой потолок данный момент, очень тяжело дается , может когда -нибудь  достигну понимания ООП, очень хочется !...

Comment: К тому же, может стоит конвертировать результат, полученный из SQL-запроса, десериализовать в класс (его нужно будет создать) и уже его вставить в таблицу?

Comment: В пейнте подчеркните строки в моём коде, которые не поняли и прикрепите сюда скриншотом. Давайте разберём их

Comment: хорошо, я вытащил данные в другую таблицу сравнивая их ID. без конвертаций studio ругается, что не может читать полученное значение при клике на строку. по этому конвертировал ID

Comment: Не совсем понял вас. Можете перефразировать?

Comment: @
Frehzy , выше выложил фотографию -результат то что хотел получит. насчет Int опечатка.

Comment: id - какое-то уникальное значение, которое только для одного порта используется? Может тогда лучше заменить его на Guid https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netframework-4.8? https://info-comp.ru/guid-in-microsoft-sql-server Вот инфа, как хранить его базе данных

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134518/discussion-between-frehzy-and-mister-junior).